# Unable to import a relative module in Python 3

Tags: python, flask, import, module

I am developing a flask project where my project structure looks like this:

```
   - shared
       - auth  
          -- __init__.py
          -- processor.py
       - config
          -- __init__.py
          -- params.py
```

I am trying to access params.py from processor.py.

My processor.py looks like this

```
from flask import Flask
from ..config.params import get_key ---> This is the issue
app = Flask(__name__)

class processor:

    @app.route("/process")
    def cur_processor():
       #some code
```

When I do `flask run` from inside the auth directory, I get this error:

```
zsh: abort      flask run
```

If I remove the relative import line, it works just fine.

How can I import properties from another directory successfully?

Answer (score 1):

I would structure the code differently :

```
  - shared
       - auth  
          -- __init__.py
       - config
          -- __init__.py
          -- params.py
       -- processor.py
```

It seems more logical to have processor.py calling others functions from a parent directory.

Comment: This does not solve the issue. The question is around accessing other modules relatively.